# Vuejs Component on Multiple DOM Elements/ Vue Instance Initialization and el Property (understanding question)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Suppose one comes from jQuery world. If one has a component `myPlugin` (jQuery plug-in, for example a component showing tooltips when one hovers on specific DOM elements) it would be initiated like this:

`$('.tooltipClass').myPlugin( { // options object here } )`

This code will select all elements with a class `tooltipClass` and will apply the `myPlugin` on them.

In Vue.js it is different and the documentation does not really make it clear. We have

```
let x = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   ...
})
```

and then we read (in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el)):

> Provide the Vue instance an existing DOM element to mount on. It can be a CSS selector string or an actual HTMLElement.

But a CSS selector could return multiple elements (it won't work for multiple elements in Vue.js - as I've already tried).

So is there a way to mimic the jQuery initialization on multiple elements in Vue.js?
(I know one could achieve it manually outside the Vue.js)

The Vue.js documentation is also quite unclear on the topic. The documentation for version 3.x does not include the `el` option at all and it is quite hard to decide from there how to proceed in cases as in the example above.

For example one creates a popup Vue.js component and wants to show it when the user clicks on different buttons on the page. The buttons may have `role='popup'` attribute in the HTML and show the parameterized popup (depending on some other `data-xxx` attributes for example).

This is pretty standard with all javascript components nowadays. How would one achieve it with Vue.js?

Comment: Vue is used to create a SPA, single page app. It only uses one element and just re-renders what's on the page using that one element as the entry point.

Comment: I agree in the SPA case it is obvious. But there is no such claim on the Vue.js page - that is only SPA framework. In contrast - they claim "An incrementally adoptable ecosystem that scales between a library and a full-featured framework." and "Unlike other monolithic frameworks, Vue is designed from the ground up to be incrementally adoptable. The core library is focused on the view layer only, and is easy to pick up and integrate with other libraries or existing projects. "

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

"Vue is also perfectly capable of powering sophisticated Single-Page Applications "

Comment: " A Vue app attaches itself to a single DOM element (#app in our case) then fully controls it. The HTML is our entry point, but everything else happens within the newly created Vue instance."

Comment: Well do you understand the difference between `Vue is also capable` and `Vue is only capable`?

Comment: If one could do `let x = new Vue({ el: '#app1', ...}); let y = new Vue({ el: '#app2', ...});` why would it not be possible to do `Vue({ el: '.class', ... })`, which will produce multiple Vue instances? It is a common pattern in the javascript world. And in Vue documentation as I stated above they say el could be a selector. What if the selector returns multiple elements? The documentation says nothing about it.
I do not want to discuss ideas here. My questions are quite concrete. Is it possible? What happens when the selector return multiple elements?

Comment: try it out and see how it goes. Typically you don't have more than one instance in an SPA.

Comment: Please read the question. I wrote there - I've already tried and it does not work.
So - do I a have a syntax mistake maybe, or is it not possible. Or is it possible in another way? The doc said nothing about it.
"Typically"  does not help any further ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach vue to multiple elements you need to create multiple Vue instances:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.sampleClass').forEach(x => new Vue({el:x}));
```

But you need to keep in mind, that Vue works in different way that jQuery. After creating Vue instance, Vue will be responsible for creating everythink inside this element, so you shouldn't use Vue to add single behaviour to existing element, rather to create whole component with all it's behaviours with Vue.

In your example with popup you should add event listener with plain javascript and when event is fired, then create Vue instance with popup.